# Rijndael: same string, different results

Tags: c#, encryption, rijndaelmanaged

We had a small desktop app that needs to be provided as a web feature now (.Net). This app contains some code for encryption and uses Rijndael classes from .Net framework. The code accepts an input string, encrypts it and writes it out the results to a file. Since all the code is contained in one class, I just copied the class to my web service application. When I encrypt the same string, using the same key, in the original app and the new app, the results are different. 
The result string given by the original app is a subset of the result string given by my web service. The latter has additional characters at the end of the encrypted string.

Below is the code I am using. Please note that I did not develop this code nor do I understand it fully. Any thoughts on the difference in behaviour? Please help!!

Here is the code that gets the user input and calls the encryptor.

```
    public void EncryptDomain(string EncryptValue, string outputDomainFile)
    {
            if (EncryptValue.Length > 0)
            {
                if ((outputDomainFile != null) && (outputDomainFile.Length > 0))
                {
                    _outputDomainFile = outputDomainFile;
                }

                byte[] input = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EncryptValue);

                Transform(input, TransformType.ENCRYPT);

            }
```

This is the encryptor code:

```
    private byte[] Transform(byte[] input, TransformType transformType)
    {
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = null;      // Stream used to encrypt
        RijndaelManaged rijndael = null;        // Rijndael provider
        ICryptoTransform rijndaelTransform = null;// Encrypting object            
        FileStream fsIn = null;                 //input file
        FileStream fsOut = null;                //output file
        MemoryStream memStream = null;          // Stream to contain data
        try
        {
            // Create the crypto objects
            rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
            rijndael.Key = this._Key;
            rijndael.IV = this._IV;
            rijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;   

            if (transformType == TransformType.ENCRYPT)
            {
                rijndaelTransform = rijndael.CreateEncryptor();
            }
            else
            {
                rijndaelTransform = rijndael.CreateDecryptor();
            }

            if ((input != null) && (input.Length > 0))
            {
                //memStream = new MemoryStream();
                //string outputDomainFile = 
                FileStream fsOutDomain = new FileStream(_outputDomainFile,
                                            FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

                cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(
                     fsOutDomain, rijndaelTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

                cryptoStream.Write(input, 0, input.Length);

                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

                //return memStream.ToArray();
                return null;
            }
            return null;

        }
        catch (CryptographicException)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Password is invalid. Please verify once again.");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (rijndael != null) rijndael.Clear();
            if (rijndaelTransform != null) rijndaelTransform.Dispose();
            if (cryptoStream != null) cryptoStream.Close();
            if (memStream != null) memStream.Close();
            if (fsOut != null) fsOut.Close();
            if (fsIn != null) fsIn.Close();
        }
 }
```

Code that sets up the IV values:

```
    private void GenerateKey(string SecretPhrase)
    {
        // Initialize internal values
        this._Key = new byte[24];
        this._IV = new byte[16];

        // Perform a hash operation using the phrase.  This will 
        // generate a unique 32 character value to be used as the key.
        byte[] bytePhrase = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SecretPhrase);
        SHA384Managed sha384 = new SHA384Managed();
        sha384.ComputeHash(bytePhrase);
        byte[] result = sha384.Hash;

        // Transfer the first 24 characters of the hashed value to the key
        // and the remaining 8 characters to the intialization vector.
        for (int loop = 0; loop < 24; loop++) this._Key[loop] = result[loop];
        for (int loop = 24; loop < 40; loop++) this._IV[loop - 24] = result[loop];
    }
```

Comment: "The code accepts an input string" - the code you've included so far accepts an input **byte array**. Show us the code that goes from a string to a byte array.

Comment: Maybe both computers run different locales?

Comment: "The string encrypted by the original app is a subset of the string encrypted by my web service. The latter has additional characters at the end of the encrypted string." So they're different strings? But you said they were the same string. Please clarify.

Comment: Why are you using `ASCII.GetBytes` instead of a variant that supports unicode, such as `Utf8.GetBytes`? And I strongly recommend using a slow hash i.e. a good Key-Derivation-Function. I prefer PBKDF2 which is offered by the Rfc2898DeriveBytes class in .net.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - Why, I do not know. As I mentioned, this is legacy code. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try UTF8.GetBytes. I am not sure where and how should I use PBKDF2. I am not very familiar with these techniques. Could you please point me to some resources?

Comment: @aakashm - My bad! I've added that code as well

Comment: @tjheuvel - As of now, they are both on the same computer

Comment: @Joe - Sorry, I meant the encrypted value. :(

Comment: The wikipedia article on Key-Derivation-Functions is a good intro. It basically replaces the SHA384 calls you have. The point of this is making then hashing slow -- which doesn't hurt the server much, but hurts a brute-forcing attacker.

Comment: Also I think you're misusing the IV. It should be random and should be stored together(for example prepended to) the cyphertext. Its effect is that if you encrypt the same data twice the cyphertext will look completely different.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Actually at this point I want that when same data is encrypted twice, the cipher text is exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that's because of the [IV (Initialisation Vector)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector)

Comment: To follow up on what DaveShaw wrote, how is `this._IV` set?  If you're not using the same Initialisatio Vector each time, you will get different results, even if the key and the string are the same.

Comment: @Tim - I have added the code that sets up the IV value. Since "SecretPhrase" is same in both cases, I would expect the IV values to be the same. Is there any way they could be different?

Comment: @tim - I verified that _IV has the same value in both cases. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic mistake. Whether you generate an IV yourself or not Rijndael (AES) will provide one for you. The trick is to always save the IV (there's a getter on RijndaelManaged).

- When you decrypt, you need to pass **both** the **Key and IV**.

If you're saving data to a file or database you can store the IV as a plain text. You can even pass the IV on wire (network, internet) as a plain text. The attacker wont be able(as far as I know) break your cipher based just on an IV. Passing or storing the IV is usually done by prefixing it in front of ciphertext or appending it at the end. (concatenating the two strings)

e.g.
CiphertextIV or IVCiphertext. (remember IV is in plaintext is it should be of a fixed length - making it easy to separate upon receiving for decryption or for database insertion)

So, if your **Key is ABCDEFABCDEFABCD** and your **IV is ABCDEF0123456789**
and this plaintext:
 **'this is some secrect text'** (let's say) produces a cipher such as: **abcd1234abcd00**

You would transmit(or store) like it this: **ABCDEF0123456789abcd1234abcd00**